# Asynchronously getting a Bitmap from managed C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have an Image Processing library written in C++ and I'm trying to load it on C# and make an application.

So far, I was able to get a Bitmap from managed C++. But the problem is, since it is dealing with a video file, I need to make some sort of a timer so that I can play frame by frame.

In order to do that, I think I should get the Bitmap before going to the next frame.  How would I get a Bitmap asynchronously?

Comment: It is usually best to leave that decision to the client code.  Call it GetFrameSlow() so it is obvious, the client programmer can deal with it by creating a Task if necessary.  If you want to *force* him to use it asynchronously (why?) then make it GetFrameAsync() that returns `Task<Bitmap>`.  Most image processing jobs are too slow to be usefully interactive so the client program just doesn't care that it is async.

Comment: @HansPassant the reason was because I want to play the video while showing the result on the image.

Comment: Hmya, what do you want to implement?  An image processing library or a video player?  Very different requirements, there is no simple answer if you want to do both.

Comment: @HansPassant Image processing library is already there and just want to use it to play a video in c# application.